Need image viewer for Windows clipboard snapshot files (.clp)
recently I found a lot of old files from the time when I still used Windows. Among them were also many Windows clipboard snapshot files (.clp). So far I haven't found an image viewer for Ubuntu which is able to display these. Any proposals?
Edit: file reports data, and file -i application/octet-stream; charset=binary

Doesn't seem to be available, uncompressed and compressed versions existed apparently: http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/PCPaint_CLP or http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/PCPaint_PIC pointed out from the first. I'd expect these to be fairly simple.

https://www.fileformat.info/format/pictor/egff.htm

Start by seeing what the files contain, with file *.clp. Please [edit]  your Question to add this information. Do not use Add Comment.

Try: https://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb

Unforunately XnViewMP seems not to be able to open the files either.
